# Ember JS: Service - Get data from Socket.io

Tags: ember.js, socket.io, ember-model

**Is this an app appropriate way to get data into a Service?**
This is what I'd like to have happen.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    model: (function() {
        var data = [];

        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

        socket.on('posts', function (data) {
            data = data.posts;
            console.log(data);
        });

        return data;
    })()
});
```

Is there a proper way to go about this?
Is this an app appropriate way to get data into a Service.
*File Location* `app/services/posts.js`

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want something like this:

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
    init() {
        const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
        socket.on('posts', data => {
            this.set('data', data.posts);
        });
    },
    data: null,
});
```

However you should know that `data` will first by `null` and then later update when the data from the socket arrives. The other way is to return a `Promise`, but with this solution you can use the socket to update your data later.